# Altering Pandas DataFrame in Function in Place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It seems like some operations can be done in place on Pandas DataFrames but some cannot.

```
def add_col(df):
    df['c'] = 5

def test_concat(df):
    df = pd.concat([df,df], ignore_index=True)
```

If I run these functions on a DataFrame, it will add a column called 'c', but it will not render the original DataFrame concatenated with itself.

Of course, I could just return the new DataFrame, but I was finding that it was impacting performance. I'm not saying that this behavior is necessarily wrong, but I'm wondering how you guys refactor a large function into smaller subfunctions without increasing memory usage and process time.

Answer (score 1):

You ask an excellent question ... I was wondering whether using
`df = df.append(df)`
would reduce the performance impact?

Comment: Good point, but defining the function as 

`def test_function_no_return(df):
    df = df.append(df)`

Doesn't seem to change the DataFrame in place either. Do you mean returning `df.append(df)`?

Comment: Yes, `append()` doesn't operate in place.  I meant returning `df.append(df)`